# calculating modulo 55 of 7 to a very large exponent

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need to calculate the reduced residue of $$7^{13198459348751983475867345892342398209234983465234531}\pmod{55}$$

However, I am not able to think of any reasonable way of calculating this. I don't think Fermat's Little Theorem applies because 55 is not prime and the only other way i can think of calculating this by writing the exponent as a sum of powers of 2 which will simply take way too long. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Where did this exponent come from?!

Answer (score 3):

Fermat's Little still applies, but in a slightly different form.

We know that $(\mathbb{Z}_{55}^\times,\times)$ forms a cyclic group and will have $\varphi(55)=40$ elements (where $\varphi(n)$ is the [Euler's Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function)).  Namely, the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{55}^\times$ are those numbers which are coprime to $55$.

Since $\gcd(7,55)=1$, you have that $7$ is in the group.  Finally, as the order of any element in a group divides the order of the group, we have that $7^{40}\equiv 1\pmod{55}$

In fact, you can find that $7^{20} \equiv 1\pmod{55}$ by trial and error and that $7^{10}\equiv 34\pmod{55}$ and $7^4\equiv 36\pmod{55}$ , so the order of $7$ is exactly $20$.

Using this, you see that only the final two digits will matter of the absurd exponent on the left of your original question, yielding a final result of $7^{11}\equiv 18\pmod{55}$.

---

In general, if you have $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then $a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.  It just so happens that for prime numbers, $\varphi(p) = p-1$, giving the familiar $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$

Comment: ah i see thanks a lot! i am new to modular arithmetic and haven't learnt all of this yet but its good to know!